# Системе тарификации

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Нужен совет по системе тарификации.

Есть пользователь у этого пользователя есть бонусы, оператор, промокоды и привязка к месту.

И еще есть таблица с тарифами и у каждого тарифа может быть правила примерно такого характера:

1. ```sql
   (
     promocode="SUPERPROMO" AND
     operator!="mts" AND
     partner="shokoladnica" AND
     bonus="platinum" AND
     brand!="tele2"
   ) OR operator="tele2"
   ```
2. ```sql
   (promocode='SUPERPROMO' and operator='tele2') or (bonus = 'platinum' and brand = 'mts')
   ```
3. ```sql
   (
     (promocode="SUPERPROMO" OR promocode="SUPER") AND
     operator!="mts" AND partner="shokoladnica" AND
     status="platinum" AND brand!="tele2"
   ) OR operator="tele2"
   ```
4. ```sql
   (
     (promocode="SUPERPROMO" AND promocode="SUPER") AND
     operator!="mts" AND partner="shokoladnica" AND
     status="platinum" AND brand!="tele2"
   ) OR operator="tele2"
   ```

И выборка должна производится с помощью данных пользователя

Можете посоветовать как лучше организовать архитектуру базы данных для записи и выборки правел?

Comment: Задача описана очень непонятно. partner - это и есть привязка к месту? brand и operator - это не одно и тоже?

Comment: Вообще, перво-наперво, предлагаю вам привести таблицы хотя бы к 3-ей нормальной форме. Вынесите Бренды, Операторов, Статусы, Партёнров, Промокоды в отдельные таблицы, а у юзеров оставьте только поля - внешние ключи. Ещё создайте таблицу Тарифы и промежуточную таблицу Условия_Тарифов. В таблице Условия_Тарифов вообще все столбцы будут внешними ключами (по одному столбцу на Бренд, Оператора, Место и т.д.). .

Comment: Отношение Тарифы -> Условия = Один -> Многие. В Условиях может быть несколько сочетаний на один тариф, например: Бренд+Место+NULL+Оператор или Бренд+Место+Промокод+NULL.

Comment: Зная данные юзера можно будет выбирать тарифы простыми условиями WHERE (operator = ? OR operator IS NULL) AND (brand= ? OR brandIS NULL)... и т.д.

Comment: Таким образом получите гибкую реляционную структуру, в которой потом будет понятно, как строить запросы. "Не знаешь, что делать с архитектурой реляционной БД - нормализуй"

Comment: brand и operator - это разные вещи. brand - это и есть привязка к месту. partner как раз привязка к клиенту

Comment: В целом сути моего совета это не меняет: нормализуйте ваши таблицы.